# which function is used for only taking up to 2 decimal and do not round value?

Tags: php, function, printf, universal-number-format

I have an issue that I do not want to round the calculated values.

For example: I have used bcdiv, bcmul, bcsub functions and

`$formattedValue = sprintf("%.2f", $numericValue);` function - is it correct? Or what should I do to round down the values?

Comment: How about `$unrounded = 0.01 * intval(100.0 * $numericValue);`? Note that `intval()` is restricted to `PHP_INT_MAX`, which is 9223372036854775807 in 64 bit systems and that this example does not explicitly format for output to the user.

Comment: `%.2f` should truncate the value down to 2 decimal places. I think that is functionally equivalent to rounding down (flooring) to 2 decimal places isn't it?

Comment: Remember that any operation that converts the _string_ output of a BC function to a float negates the entire point of using BC in the first place, and will reintroduce floating point inaccuracy back into your values. If you just want the string truncated, then truncate the string. `bcmul()` itself will happily do what you want via simply `bcmul($value, 1, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$formattedValue = floor($numericValue * 100) / 100;
```

and

```
$formattedValue = number_format(floor($numericValue * 100) / 100, 2, '.', '');
```

like this:

```
$numericValue = '2.789';
$numericValue = floor((float)$numericValue * 100) / 100; // Convert to float, multiply by 100, floor it, then divide by 100
$formattedValue = number_format($numericValue, 2, '.', ''); // Format to 2 decimal places
```

Comment: `floor()` is a good choice, it is not limited by `PHP_INT_MAX`. Your answer would get my upvote if you explained why this works and what the difference is between the two lines of code.

Comment: Instead, you can use the floor() function in combination with * 100 and / 100 as mentioned before.
and If you want to format it as a string with two decimal places, you can then use number_format().

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I meant I will upvote your answer if you edit your answer and add an explanation and what the difference between the 2 lines is. This is not for me, but for other readers of your answer.

Comment: If you want to round down values in PHP, you can use the floor() function. This function rounds fractions down, meaning it returns the next lowest integer value by rounding down the value if necessary.

However, the floor() function does not work with strings, and the BCMath functions you mentioned (bcdiv, bcmul, bcsub) return strings. So, you need to convert the string to a float before using floor(). After that, you can use number_format() to format the number to 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Asif if you have something unique to share on this topic, please transfer your unique advice to the duplicate target listed at the top of the page.

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Comment: @KIK Please encourage contributors to add any unique insights on this topic to the canonical.